# What can this be in my dog's skin?

Tags: dogs, health, skin-condition, infections

My dog's had these spots in her skin for some time. I'm including photos of the lesions. They're very itchy; she's always scratching herself. They also smell.

What can it be and what medication can I buy? I prefer medication that can be taken orally because it's very hard for my parents to put ointments, creams, etc. on her.

I bathe her biweekly with an oatmeal shampoo for dogs.

We live in a very hot environment where the temp's been over 90 °F (32 °C) the last few weeks. She sleeps most of the day.

I don't believe she's in pain; she wags her tail, eats well, runs and walks normally, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't wash your dog if it isn't necessary. This might be some irritation due to washing but it could also be some allergic reaction to something else. Better show or at least ask your vet about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to bring your dog to the vet.**

Stop reading this, call your vet, get your dog there now - it looks like a skin infection*.

These can happen for a variety of reasons, but the only course of treatment is antibiotics (you may also need a medicated shampoo, and possibly steroids depending on the severity).  You need a prescription from a vet for antibiotics, there is nothing you can buy over the counter.

*I'm not a vet, but I have long haired dogs who are prone to skin issues.  Every time I've seen lesions like this it has been a skin infection.

Answer (score 3):

It could also be a fungus. You stated that you live in a hot environment, but is it humid as well? If it is, those spots could be a fungus. To be sure and to get the proper medication, you would need a vet to diagnose them.